# I can't execute file from shared folder in Windows 2003

Tags: file-permissions, windows-server-2003

I'm working on Windows Server 2003 (Polish version but it doesn't matter, I suppose). I created shared folder which contains some .exe file. I added full control on file and folder to everybody wherever I could. I'm trying to run this file using shared folder path but I get
error:

[image]

The error message in English is **Windows cannot access the specified device path or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the item.**

I'm working on admin account. When I execute this file locally everything works, when I do it with the same account through shared folder, I've got error.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you try use Remote Access (or any remote access program, for example VNC, LogMeIn etc.) and login to server and run this exe file? If its works, i think this program try to run in your Windows and not server.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Internet Explorer Settings, security tab.
Click Local Internet and add new Web to zone.

file://file_name_server

Confirm all.

This is problem with enchanced Internet Security on Windows 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you share a folder there are two things you need to do:

1st:
Set the permissions on the share

2nd:
Go to Security tab and set the local file / folder security.

Once you do both, things should work for you. Also note that since you want to launch and executable, both read and execute permissions need to be granted to the users in both the places.